# Counting rows in two different tables grouped under the third table

Tags: join, count

I am trying to count the number of events occurring in two different tables grouped under the third table. The problem is I am getting the same numbers for the tables!

I tried without NOT null. It changes the numbers but the cloumns numbers are same!!

here is my code!

```
SELECT registration.device_type, 
COUNT(super_trees.events) as super_trees_sends,
COUNT(free_trees.events) as  free_trees_sends 
FROM registration 
full join super_trees on super_trees.user_id = registration.user_id  
full join free_trees on free_trees.user_id = registration.user_id 
WHERE super_trees.events IS NOT NULL
AND free_trees.events IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY registration.device_type;
```

Comment: I am guessing because there isn't any data provided. It seems like you might want to use OR instead of AND in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
SELECT DISTINCT(registration.device_type), abc.super_trees_sends, abcd.free_trees_sends FROM registration
left join(SELECT device_type, COUNT(events) as super_trees_sends FROM super_trees join registration on super_trees.user_id = registration.user_id GROUP BY device_type ORDER BY super_trees_sends DESC
) abc on registration.device_type = abc.device_type
left join(SELECT device_type, COUNT(events) as free_trees_sends FROM free_trees join registration on free_trees.user_id = registration.user_id GROUP BY device_type ORDER BY free_trees_sends DESC
) abcd on registration.device_type = abcd.device_type
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, explain how it is an answer to the question & what the problems or misconceptions in the question were. Please don't answer unclear questions; downvote, close vote/flag & comment requesting clarification. I know that's your question. So edit it.